# Getting "not a valid month" when executing a dbms_scheduler.create_job?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my table and values:

```
CREATE TABLE Individuo
(
  id_ind int primary key,
  nom_ind Varchar(255),
  ape_ind Varchar(255),
  usr_ind Char(10)
)

DROP table Individuo;

insert into Individuo values(1, 'Carlos', 'Guzman', 'CG92');
insert into Individuo values(2, 'Hidalgo', 'Machado', 'HM88');
insert into Individuo values(3, 'Guillermo', 'Pinto', 'GP68');
insert into Individuo values(4, 'Katia', 'Barba', 'KB87');
insert into Individuo values(5, 'Fernando', 'Parra', 'FP77');
insert into Individuo values(6, 'Celesta', 'Valdes', 'CV');
insert into Individuo values(7, 'Carola', 'Vallez', 'CV92');
insert into Individuo values(8, 'Catalina', 'Riveron', 'CR75');
insert into Individuo values(9, 'Pepe', 'Najarro', 'PN83');
insert into Individuo values(10, 'Paz', 'Cuenca', 'PC74');
insert into Individuo values(11, 'Benedicto', 'Moscoso', 'BM92');
insert into Individuo values(12, 'Rosaline', 'Davila', 'RD88');
insert into Individuo values(13, 'Hector', 'Castellon', 'HC83');
insert into Individuo values(14, 'Leonora', 'Basco', 'LB80');
```

I am creating a job in oracle 11g express and I am getting an error that says: "not a valid month". What is wrong with my start date format?

I also want to know if end date should have the word "Null" if i want my job to execute forever and if I need an auto increase in my inserted value for the job to be able to work correctly.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'mi_trabajo',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'INSERT INTO Individuo VALUES(15, "Beatriz", "Armando", "BA79");',
   start_date           => '14-JAN-16 14.00.00 PM America/Bogota',
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYMINUTE=0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55', 
   end_date             => 'Null',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'La insercion en la tabla Individuo tuvo exito');
END;
```

Comment: 1) your NLS setting may not be properly doing an implicit to_date on the start_Date format, so put it into a to_Date() function. Item 2) remove the quotes from around the NULL for end_Date. You need to set it to null, not a string containing the word null.

Comment: Use `start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP` - that is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure [expects a timestamp with timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300) for the start date. You are passing a string. You are therefore relying on implicit conversion of that string, which depends on your NLS settings.

From the error it looks like you have your NLS_LANGUAGE set to English but your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE set to something else, perhaps Spanish from the time zone you're using. I can simulate the error with:

```
select to_timestamp_tz('14-JAN-16 14.00.00 PM America/Bogota',
  'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH')
from dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Firstly you should explicitly convert the string to the right type, rather than relying on implicit conversion:

```
to_timestamp_tz('14-JAN-16 14.00.00 PM America/Bogota',
  'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS PM TZR')
```

... except you cant have the hour as '14' when using the AM/PM indicator:

```
to_timestamp_tz('14-JAN-16 02.00.00 PM America/Bogota',
  'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS PM TZR')
```

or

```
to_timestamp_tz('14-JAN-16 14.00.00 America/Bogota',
  'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS TZR')
```

That still relies on your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE being English, otherwise JAN won't be recognised. You can use `'ENE'` instead (sticking with Spanish), and/or you can include the date language in the call:

```
to_timestamp_tz('14-JAN-16 14.00.00 PM America/Bogota',
  'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

but it's better to use month numbers to avoid the ambiguity, and if you're doing that you might as well use four-digit years, e.g.:

```
to_timestamp_tz('2016-01-14 14:00:00 America/Bogota',
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR')
```

Or since you've gone that far, use a [timestamp with time zone literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51065):

```
timestamp '2016-01-14 14:00:00 America/Bogota'
```

In your call that would be:

```
...
start_date => timestamp '2016-01-14 14:00:00 America/Bogota',
...
```

---

And as @MichaelBroughton pointed out, the `end_date` should not have quotes around it - you're passing an invalid string (which will get ORA-01858 with your implicit format mask, I think). Use just `end_date => null,` or don't pass it at all.

---

And your job action has an invalid insert statement; you've used double-quotes around the values you're using, which means they'll be treated as identifiers - and they don't exist. If it runs you should see error (in `user_scheduler_job_run_details`). You probably meant to escape the single-quotes around the values - which is two single quotes (`''`) not a double quote (`"`):

```
job_action => 'INSERT INTO Individuo (id_ind, nom_ind, ape_ind, usr_ind) VALUES(15, ''Beatriz'', ''Armando'', ''BA79'');',
```

It will fail on the second run anyway because primary key 15 will already exist, so even as an experiment this doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: The quoted null for the end_date may also be what's blowing up the implicit formatting

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - yes indeed, hadn't spotted that was quoted. Although with my NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT set to the same pattern the OP seems to be using, `to_timestamp_tz('NULL')` gets ORA-01858.

Comment: yeah, I hadn't noticed the 14 PM, so its a tag team effort on this one :)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I didn't notice that I didn't take off the PM after the 14.

Comment: I executed the job I made, the problem is that I am not seeing anything when using: SELECT * FROM user_scheduler_jobs WHERE job_name = 'mi_trabajo';

Comment: Oracle is real big on saving identifiers in upper-case. Check for MI_TRABAJO

Comment: yeah, it showed my job action when using the user_scheduler_jobs but when i use select * from Individuo I dont see anything being inserted. Am I supposed to see a new row inserted every 5 minutes in the user_scheduler_jobs or in my table? .... I followed Alex Poole suggestion of using uppercase and I see my job but I dont know what is the job supposed to do other than showing a single row user_scheduler_jobs . No I did not get any other errors.

Comment: @EAlexisT - did you get errors from the job running? Your insert statement is invalid too. Updated to show how to escape the quotes. (You may also have to wrap it in a PL/SQL block; I've never tried to run plain SQL from a job, but it may be OK with an insert).

Comment: No, I only got  "PL / SQL procedure successfully completed." But i dont see any rows being inserted every 5 minutes in my table or in the user_scheduler_job